# How to show SKU before woocommerce product title on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show the SKU before title of product in woocommerce. Here is a code what I'm trying bellow code show the SKU after price on Woocommerce archive page. But is there any hook available to show it before the product title on archive page ?

I use `woocommerce_get_price_html` this hook to show it after price I also try `the_title` but it override the menu also.

```
function rupom_custom_price_sku( $price ) { 
    global $woocommerce , $product;
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()){
        return $price . '<br /><span class="price-sku" style="color:red">Item # ' . $sku . '</span>';
    }

    else { 
        return $price; 
    } 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'rupom_custom_price_sku' );
```

Comment: `global $woocommerce` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, use the `WC()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` is the hook you need to use

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_before_title' );
function custom_before_title() {

    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        echo $product->get_sku();
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not working:(  my woocommerce version is 2.5.1   Take a look here http://162.144.251.20/~hubcaps/product-category/custom-hubcaps/

Comment: your theme might have removed that hook. try switching to Twenty Sixteen theme and then see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes You are right my theme remove this it works on default theme like Twenty Sixteen

Comment: But If the Loop not start then is it possible to get the SKU?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Not sure what you mean by `if the loop not start`, have a look at `plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`